# Does for-await-of wait for the current iteration to complete before going to the next?

Tags: javascript, async-await

Given a loop like:

```
for await(let line of readFileLineByLine('./long-file.txt')) {
    const interestingFacts = await processLine(line);
}
```

Where `readFileLineByLine` returns an AsyncGenerator, will this start processing the 2nd line before or after `await processLine` returns? (assuming the 2nd line is ready before `processLine` completes)

And if not, how would one parallelize this? (so that many lines can be processed simultaneously)

Comment: Wait, does that syntax even work?

Comment: @slebetman yes works [`for await of MDN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of)

Comment: Isn't it the whole point of `for await ..of`?

Comment: @Clarity Apparently not! I don't know what the difference between putting `await` beside `for` vs inside the body is :\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `for await` loop is a syntactic sugar for the following:

```
let generator = readFileLineByLine();

while (true) {
    let promise = generator.next();
    let item = await promise;

    if (item.done)
        break;

    let line = item.value;
    await processLine(line)

}
```

So the answer is yes, `readLine(nextLine)` won't start until `processLine(previousLine)` completes.

If you want two functions not to depend on each other, one option would be to make `readFileLineByLine` non-async, that is, just `yield` pending promises. Consume this generator normally, attach `then(processLine)` to each promise and await them all:

```
let promises = [];

for (let promise of readFileLineByLinePending())
    promises.push(promise.then(processLine))

await Promise.all(promises)
```

Here's a demo:

```js
async function delay(n) {
    return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, n))
}


async function processLine(s) {
    console.log('process BEGIN:', s)
    await delay(300);
    console.log('process END:', s)
}

async function* readFileLineByLine() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        console.log('read BEGIN', i)
        await delay(500);
        let t = await 'line' + i;
        console.log('read END', i)
        yield t;

    }
}

function* readFileLineByLinePending() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        console.log('readPending BEGIN', i)
        let t = delay(500).then(() => {
            console.log('readPending END', i);
            return 'line' + i;
        });
        yield t;

    }
}


async function main() {

    console.time('async gen')

    for await(let line of readFileLineByLine())
       await processLine(line)

    console.log('----------------------------------------')
    console.timeEnd('async gen')
    console.log('----------------------------------------')


    console.time('sync gen')

    let promises = [];

    for (let promise of readFileLineByLinePending())
        promises.push(promise.then(processLine))

    await Promise.all(promises)

    console.log('----------------------------------------')
    console.timeEnd('sync gen')
    console.log('----------------------------------------')
}

main().then(() => console.log('done'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 5):

The next iteration will only start after the last iteration completes. This can be easily shown by `await`ing inside the `for` loop:

```js
const asyncIterable = {
  [Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
    return {
      i: 0,
      next() {
        if (this.i < 3) {
          return Promise.resolve({ value: this.i++, done: false });
        }

        return Promise.resolve({ done: true });
      }
    };
  }
};

const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

(async function() {
   for await (let num of asyncIterable) {
     console.log('start ' + num);
     await delay(1000);
     console.log('end ' + num);
   }
})();
```

To parallelize, you can call a function (but don't wait for it to resolve) and push the (new) Promise to an array, then call `Promise.all` on the array:

```js
const asyncIterable = {
  [Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
    return {
      i: 0,
      next() {
        if (this.i < 3) {
          return Promise.resolve({ value: this.i++, done: false });
        }

        return Promise.resolve({ done: true });
      }
    };
  }
};

const processNum = num => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));

(async function() {
   console.log('start');
   const proms = [];
   for await (let num of asyncIterable) {
     proms.push(processNum(num));
   }
   await Promise.all(proms);
   console.log('all done (1000ms)');
})();
```

(because the number of items returned by the iterable isn't known in advance, something cleaner-looking like `.map` isn't possible, unfortunately)